# angle-bracket components not working

Tags: ember.js

```
ember-cli@1.3.8 
ember@2.1.0
```

I manually updated ember and ember-data to 2.1.0 inside package.json.  I am running the app from the dummy app in an ember addon project.

When I do the following

```
<my-component model={{model}} />
```

I get the following rendered in HTML.

```
<my-component model="<dummy@model:employee::ember395:null>"></my-component>
```

And the component is not rendered at all.  I put a breakpoint in the `init` method but it is never called.  I seems to me the the component is not recognised for some reason.

It works if I use handlebars syntax:

```
{{my-component model=model}}
```

Is there something I need to enable in ember-cli or ember for this to work?  Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that maybe they aren't supported in 2.1.0 yet as described [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/08/13/ember-2-0-released.html#toc_ember-2-x-themes) which suggests they might be supported in 2.2.0.

I was able to make my curly components attributes readonly like this:

```
{{my-component model=(readonly model)}}
```

Therefore the refactor later should be pretty simple.